# Why do I get this error :AttributeError: 'Fetch_Info' object has no attribute 'driver' when I run my selenium_web.py script

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, driver, attributeerror

I want to launch the web browser from my script file but when I run my code it gives me an error as 'AttributeError: 'Infow' object has no attribute 'driver'.

I tried finding a solution to this by uninstalling the current version of selenium 4.4.0 and reinstalling a previous version by running the command `pip install selenium==4.0.0.b4` but this did not solve my problem. My code is supposed to open the web browser when I run it but it is not. How do I fix this?

My code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


 class Fetch_Info:
def __int__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path="C:\\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\\PycharmProjects\\Voice_Recognition_Virtual_Assistan\\chromedriver.exe")

def get_info(self, query):
    self.query = query
    self.driver.get(url='https://www.wikipedia.org')
    search = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchInput"]')
    search.click()
    search.send_keys(query)
    enter = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-form"]/fieldset/button')
    enter.click()


assist = Fetch_Info()
assist.get_info("hello")
```

The error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\PycharmProjects\Voice_Recognition_Virtual_Assistant\selenium_web.py", line 19, in <module>
assist.get_info("hello") 


"C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\PycharmProjects\Voice_Recognition_Virtual_Assistant\selenium_web.py", 
 line 15, in get_info
self.driver.get(url='https://www.wikipedia.org')
 AttributeError: 'Fetch_Info' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

@Rukamakama below is the error I'm having after making the correction

```
 C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\PycharmProjects\Voice_Recognition_Virtual_Assist 
 ant\selenium_web.py:10: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been 
    deprecated, please pass in a Service object
   self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
  Traceback (most recent call last):
 File 
     
    "C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\Desktop\virtual_assistant_env\lib\site- 
     packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in 
      start
   self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Program 


Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
     File "C:\Program 
Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file 
specified

  During handling of the above exception, another exception 
  occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):

    File `"C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\PycharmProjects\Voice_Recognition_Virtual_Assistant\selenium_web.py", line 23, in <module>
assist = Fetch_Info()`


File"C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\PycharmProjects\Voice_Recognition_Virtual_Assistant\selenium_web.py", line 10, in __init__
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(



File "C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\Desktop\virtual_assistant_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
```

File "C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\Desktop\virtual_assistant_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 90, in **init**
self.service.start()

File "C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\Desktop\virtual_assistant_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 84, in start
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__()` function is missing a `i`.
Please update your code from:

`def __int__(self)`

to:

`def __init__(self)`

Comment: Thank you.  I have fixed that but this time I'm having a different error